# Create Dynamic Expression Tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, lambda

How do I convert this  Lambda To Expression tree in C#

```
var FieldName="SomeDynamicField";
var param = "SomeParam"
//Lambda to beCreated
x=>x.FieldName!=null && x.FieldName.ToLower().Contains(param )
```

I have tried this so far

```
private static Expression GetPropertyExpression(PropertyInfo prop, ParameterExpression paramExpr, ConstantExpression valueExpr) { 
    var memberAcc = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramExpr, prop); 
    Console.WriteLine(memberAcc); 
    var containsMember = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"); 
    var toLower= typeof(String).GetMethod("ToLower",new [] {typeof(string)}); 
    var ttt=Expression.Call(memberAcc,containsMember, valueExpr); 
    return Expression.Call(memberAcc,containsMember, valueExpr); 
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have been trying to write this code to filter any List.it works but on uppercase

Comment: private static Expression GetPropertyExpression(PropertyInfo prop, ParameterExpression paramExpr, ConstantExpression valueExpr)
 {
  var memberAcc = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramExpr, prop);
  // Console.WriteLine(memberAcc);
  var containsMember = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
  var toLower= typeof(String).GetMethod("ToLower",new [] {typeof(string)});
  var ttt=Expression.Call(memberAcc,containsMember, valueExpr);
  return  Expression.Call(memberAcc,containsMember, valueExpr);
 }

Comment: Please add the code to your question, not in a comment, at least there you can format it in a good way (use the [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43966333/edit) link under your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it yourself slightly easier. Instead of using `Contains` method, which interestingly doesn't support the `StringComparison` to be passed as parameters, you can use the `IndexOf` method.

You can implement it like so:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ContainsValue<T>(string fieldName, string val) {
    var type = typeof(T);
    var member = Expression.Parameter(type, "param");
    var memberExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField( member, fieldName);
    var targetMethod = memberExpression.Type.GetMethod( "IndexOf", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) } );
    var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call( memberExpression, targetMethod, Expression.Constant(val), Expression.Constant( StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>( 
        Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.NotEqual(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(null)), 
            Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual( methodCallExpression, Expression.Constant(0) )
        ), 
        member
    );
}
```

The trick here being that I combine the `IndexOf` method with a `GreaterThanOrEqual` call with a value of 0.

This in the end gives for a test class following expression

```
((param.Parameter != null) AndAlso (param.Parameter.IndexOf("test", CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
```

An example, you can find here on the [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uj9bgg), but I also added the full code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ContainsValue<T>(string fieldName, string val) {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var member = Expression.Parameter(type, "param");
        var memberExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField( member, fieldName);
        var targetMethod = memberExpression.Type.GetMethod( "IndexOf", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) } );
        var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call( memberExpression, targetMethod, Expression.Constant(val), Expression.Constant( StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) );

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>( 
            Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.NotEqual(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(null)), 
                Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual( methodCallExpression, Expression.Constant(0) )
            ), 
            member
        );
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new List<Test>() {
            new Test() { Parameter = "Alpha" },
            new Test(),
            new Test() { Parameter = "Test" },
            new Test() { Parameter = "test" },
            new Test() { Parameter = "TEST" },
            new Test() { Parameter = "Contains test" }
        };
        var expr = ContainsValue<Test>("Parameter",  "test");
        // you can see the body here
        Console.WriteLine( expr.Body );
        // and the result
        var results = items.Where( expr.Compile() ).Select(t => t.Parameter).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine( "Results: {0}", string.Join( ",", results ));
        Console.WriteLine( "Total results: {0}", results.Count );
    }

    public class Test {
        public string Parameter { get;set; }
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
((param.Parameter != null) AndAlso (param.Parameter.IndexOf("test", CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
Results: Test,test,TEST,Contains test
Total results: 4
```

Comment: Thanks Icepickle, I would like it to work for classes with common data types like strings, decimals,doubles and so on. Currently it works so well but on string fields only

Comment: @EmmanuelOgoma That is ofcourse possible, for that there are many different expressions available. However, they don't have Contains method for example, there is lots more to be done. Depending on how you wish to combine expressions afterwards it can be quite some work ;)

Comment: this lambda works but i do not know how to create its expression. note the Tostring method called x=>x.FieldName!=null && x.FieldName.Tostring().ToLower().Contains(param )

Comment: @EmmanuelOgoma I think you oversimplify it a bit, but ofcourse from your question, it's very hard to know you context. Or maybe I see it to complex :)

Comment: If you want, we can [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144207/discussion-between-emmanuel-ogoma-and-icepickle) about your requirements